# How can I upgrade Git via Chocolatey from within Git For Windows?

Tags: windows, git, chocolatey

I use Chocolatey to manage as many Windows applications as I can, including Git. I use Git For Windows (`git-cmd.exe`) as my default command prompt.

But this means that if I do a `choco upgrade all -y` in G4W, and one of the upgrades is to Git, an error occurs when choco tries to replace `git-cmd.exe`.

Is there any way to upgrade Git via Chocolatey from within G4W? Alternatively, is there a way to get Chocolatey to skip over Git upgrades (at which point I'd notice and switch to regular `cmd.exe` for that upgrade)?

Answer (score 1):

A recent addition to Chocolatey was the concept of "upgrade all except...".

You can find details about this in the issue that was tracking this:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/pull/343

As a result of this addition, you should be able to do the following:

`choco upgrade all --except="skype,conemu"`

Comment: However, this is not available except in the prerelease and will be available in 0.9.10+.

Comment: See, I knew there was something I missed in this post :-)  I thought this had snuck into stable, but I only have the pre-release on my machine, so wasn't in a position to verify :-D